# Fetching email_verified check condition data from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

In my L-6 project I want check data and show: if email_verified_at users data table is verified then print Verified or else Not:

```
<td>
  @if(auth()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())
     Verified
  @else
      No verified
  @endif
```

After using this line of code I got error

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Call to a member function
>   hasVerifiedEmail() on null (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\admin\userList.blade.php)

So Have any one any idea about this!

Comment: @Bhoomi patel plz post in ans section. I have no authority of approve edit at this level.

Comment: i m not posted answer. i m just edited your question

Answer (score 0):

When user is not logged, `auth()->user()` returns null and you cannot run method on null. To solve this you can use:

```
@if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())
```

or even simpler using [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```
@if(optional(auth()->user())->hasVerifiedEmail())
```

instead of

```
@if(auth()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())
```